# Runtime Error when import matplotlib on window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to import matplotlib in pycharm but getting a runtime error. I've tried to reinstall and trying to run in CMD but still, it doesn't work. Appreciate help here.

[image: The screen shot]

Comment: How does your Error look? 
Is it something like this: `RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation (...) fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.` ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the text directly here on SO. See here for an explanation why: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Could you please post the error message, and the code?

Comment: Hi, below is the detail of the error:

Comment: import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.4\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nisha\PycharmProjects\matplotlib_tut\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.4\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import

Comment: module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nisha\PycharmProjects\matplotlib_tut\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\nisha\PycharmProjects\matplotlib_tut\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\nisha\\PycharmProjects\\matplotlib_tut\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should run

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

first in the command line.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same error when trying to import matplotlib